# How to email users in multiple arrays, the Rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I have a `Project` that has three arrays:

- `admins`
- `members`
- `readers`

I want to email the various users in each of those arrays.
Am currently doing it like:

```
@project.admins.each do |u|
  ProjelementMailer.notify_update(u)
end

@project.members.each do |u|
  ProjelementMailer.notify_update(u)
end

@project.readers.each do |u|
  ProjelementMailer.notify_update(u)
end
```

Is there a more DRY Rails approach that lets me express this in a more concise way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine all the arrays:

```
(@project.admins + @project.members + @project.readers).each do |u|
  ProjelementMailer.notify_update(u)
end
```

You may also wish to call `uniq` on the combined array to remove duplicates. For a more literal dynamic approach:

```
[:admins, :members, :readers].each do |sym|
  @project.send(sym).each do |u|
    ProjelementMailer.notify_update(u)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Also appreciate the code with more literal dynamic approach.

Comment: @DanielMay Dynamic languages allow for many, many ways to accomplish the same (or similar) task. There is rarely one *best* solution, but it is always nice to explore them to find which one makes the most sense for a given application.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't grow up so much with dynamic languages and am trying to get acclimatised as much as possible to patterns (and anti-patterns). Thanks for your help on this :)

Answer (score 1):

you can join all arrays using | for all uniq users  and call each on it, but make sure all methods admins, members, readers are not returning nil object

```
(@project.admins | @project.members | @project.readers).each do |u|
  ProjelementMailer.notify_update(u)
end
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about `|` with arrays. Though don't call it bitwise OR, because it's not—[it's a method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-7C) that performs a union.

Comment: I know what it is, but you're saying it's something very different by saying "| (bit or)" in your answer.

Comment: Thanks Naren, helpful! Discussion also helpful